# Convert datetime to specific format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, formatdatetime

How to convert datetime to this format : `2019/06/17 18:00:00.123`

I use `select convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)` and `select convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)` together but I get only `2019/06/17 18:00:00`

I can't find a combination to get format I need. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FORMAT` to return the `DATETIME` in a specified format (assuming you use SQL-Server and want to return a `string` type).

```
DECLARE @example DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT FORMAT(@example, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff');
```

Comment: This only applies to SQL Server 2012 onwards. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @PeterSmith . . . Given that in three weeks, SQL Server 2012 will be the oldest supported version, this is not exactly a limitation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed but there are a large number of 2008R2 servers still in use.

Answer (score 0):

use datetime2 data type and cast getdate to datetime2(3) for 3 digit precesion

```
select cast( getdate() as DATETIME2(3))
```

Comment: Thank you for answe. I am quite unexpierenced with this so can I ask you for help? Where should I put this cast command in this code? [T1]=convert(nvarchar,convert(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, T1), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) ,111)+' '+convert(nvarchar, convert(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, T1), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))),108)

Comment: @DušanRanduška post in your question